# Show the submitted values in the form when validation fails

Tags: forms, options, settings-api, validation

Currently I do:

```
$options = get_option( 'jons-plugin-options' );
        echo "<input id='jons-plugin-options[field-two]' name='jons-plugin-options[field-two]' size='4' type='text' value='" . $options['field-two'] . "' />";
```

But it does not get the submitted form value and display it when I do:

```
add_settings_error( 'field-two', 'field-two', 'Field two must not be 0.' );
return false;
```

In the register_setting callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If you're using the settings API correctly, here's what happens when you try to save your options:

1. Form posts to `options.php`
2. WordPress handles $_POST and runs `update_option` on your registered settings
3. Your sanitize callback from `register_setting` is applied
4. Any data that fails/you don't return in your callback isn't saved
5. WordPress redirects back to your options page (`GET`)

Now you're back on your options page, with the error message, but the data wasn't written to the database and now `$_POST` will be empty.

The only way I can see around it is to store the "incorrect" data in another option, inside your sanitize callback, for use on the returned page.

Answer (score 0):

here is how I handled the problem.
Hope it might help someone.

```
/**
 * Add a validation callback to the settings form
 */
public function options_update()
{
    register_setting($this->plugin_name, $this->plugin_name, array($this, 'validate'));
}

/**
 * Validates and sanitizes the submitted values
 * @param $input
 * @return array
 */
public function validate($input)
{
    $valid = array();

    $valid['is_api_enabled'] = (isset($input['is_api_enabled']) && !empty($input['is_api_enabled'])) ? 1 : 0;
    $valid['api_key'] = (isset($input['api_key'])) ? $input['api_key'] : '';

    if ($valid['is_api_enabled'] === 1) {
        if (!$valid['api_key'] || empty(trim($valid['api_key']))) {
            add_settings_error($this->plugin_name, 'api_key', __('API key is mandatory if API is enabled'));

            $this->revert_setting($valid, $this->plugin_name, 'api_key');
            $this->revert_setting($valid, $this->plugin_name, 'is_api_enabled');
        }
    }

    // only return accepted values (old ones or correct)
    return $valid;
}

/**
 * Revert the submitted setting to its original value
 * @param $new
 * @param $option
 * @param null $key
 */
private function revert_setting(&$new, $option, $key = null)
{
    $old = get_option($option);

    if ($key) {
        $new[$key] = array_key_exists($key, $old) ? $old[$key] : null;
    } else {
        $new = $old;
    }
}
```